# How can I create a POV scene with no camera movement?

Tags: video

I'd like to create a POV scene where my hands are visible doing something, but the camera must not move.

Something like this (jump to 1:00)

I think some kind of POV gear which is mounted to the body is not working here, since there's absolutely no movement of the camera.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a stable mount that keeps the camera strictly in position. Then work from behind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the camera is not mounted to the body in that example.

Instead, use a tripod or work surface mount to hold you camera in front of you. For modern small cameras, it is easy to ensure it does not get in your way.